# .NET Framework vs .NET Core - Adding cert to a RESTful API call works in one, not the other

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, ssl, client-certificates

I have a common RESTful API end point that two applications are hitting - one of them is in .NET Core 3.1 and the other is in .NET Framework 4.7.2.  Both are using similar code to retrieve the certificate (a PFX file), attaching that cert to an HTTP handler and then creating an HTTP Client using that handler as shown:

```
var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
X509Certificate2 cert = null;
var password = new AzureKeyVault(_configuration).GetPassword(_secretUri).Result;
try 
{
    cert = new X509Certificate2(currentDirectory + _certName, password);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Error trying to retrieve certificate named " + currentDirectory + _certName + " - exception was " + ex.Message);
}
      
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
                
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
     
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                    
    return responseContent;
}
        
throw new ApplicationException($"Status code: {response.StatusCode}, Error: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
```

The .NET Core code works; the .NET Framework code does not.  The .NET Framework gets an exception that no SSL/TLS connection could be made.  Using Wireshark, I found that I am indeed using TLS 1.2 which is required for the endpoint.  However, the .NET Core call has the certificate present whereas the .NET Framework call does not.

Investigating this further on the .NET Framework side, I see that the private key is not available on the Certificate.  In the .NET Core code, it is available (see below).

.NET Core (correct)
[image: .NET Core screenshot]

.NET Framework (incorrect)
[image: .NET Framework screenshot]

The cert being retrieved is from the exact same directory and both are running on the exact same machine.
I should also mention that the .NET Core code is a RESTful API itself; the .NET Framework code is a simple console application (thus eliminating all the permissions issues with IIS).  If I do a call in the debugger's Immediate Window of 'cert.GetRSAPrivateKey()', I do get an RSA key back...so maybe the above screen shots is just a symptom of the debugger.

I am *guessing* that the lack of the private key on the .NET Framework side is the problem.  Or maybe this has nothing to do with it - but at the end of the day, the cert is on the packet from .NET Core but not from .NET Framework using essentially the exact same code.  Any thoughts on this issue would be greatly appreciated as a number of us are stumped.  Thanks in advance!

**EDIT #1:**
Below is the debugger trace output showing - what I believe - is .NET Framework concluding that there are no certs available to pick from with the request:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [14200] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 12ed470:6ee7d30, targetName = xxxx.xxx.com, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [14200] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=CredentialsNeeded).
System.Net Information: 0 : [14200] SecureChannel#7894961 - We have user-provided certificates. The server has specified 1 issuer(s). Looking for certificates that match any of the issuers.
System.Net Information: 0 : [14200] SecureChannel#7894961 - Left with 0 client certificates to choose from.
```

Also here are the Wireshark entries showing certs on .NET Core calls, but not on the .NET Framework calls:

.NET Core (correct):

```
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Multiple Handshake Messages
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 4262
        Handshake Protocol: Certificate
            Handshake Type: Certificate (11)
            Length: 3924
            Certificates Length: 3921
            Certificates (3921 bytes)
                Certificate Length: 1957
                Certificate: ... <removed rest for brevity>
```

.NET Framework (incorrect):

```
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Multiple Handshake Messages
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 77
        Handshake Protocol: Certificate
            Handshake Type: Certificate (11)
            Length: 3
            Certificates Length: 0
```

Comment: The certificate is stored in the user IE settings.  So is both application running with same user account?  if you are running a server it start up is a System Account with no environment.  You may want to start the service AS ADMIN account that has the certificate installed.

Comment: @jdweng - both are running (being debugged) within Visual Studio (Standard Visual Studio for .NET Framework; Visual Studio Code for .NET Core) - so both would be running under my user account.  I tried running VS as an admin, but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Why would one app be able to get the certificate store and the other not be able to get the store if you are using the same user account?  Do a search for certificate on following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1

Comment: @jdweng - This isn't actually getting the cert from the store (although I added it to the store in an attempt to fix this problem which didn't work).  As shown in the code in my original post, the cert is coming from a file.  And I'm not having any issues retrieving the certificate, the debugger shows the certificate is attached to the handler - but somehow for some reason .NET Framework is removing the certificate upon sending the request.

Comment: Removing what?  The file or the runtime object? Most APIs are very robust and reads all the properties in the certificate to determine what type of certificate you have and the encryption methods to use based on the certificate and and the encryption mode being used.  In c# you have to do similar.  Suppose the certificate was TLS 1.3 then you code would encrypt using TLS 1.3.  And if the certificate was for TLS 1.2 then you would encrypt using TLS 1.2.  If your code only contained TLS 1.2 and the certificate was TLS 1.3 you would fail.  The API supports both type certificates.

Comment: What you could do is use a sniffer like fiddler which indicates the encryption mode being used and check what mode the working API used.  Then modify your c# code to use same mode.

Comment: @jdweng - The encryption mode is TLS 1.2; that's not the problem.  The handshake with the API is happening successfully - the certificate in the payload is **missing** with the .NET Framework code but it is present with the .NET Core code.  That's the problem - the question is why is the cert not making it as part of the request when it is clearly in the http handler when debugging the code.

Comment: Then use a sniffer and compare headers first request between working and non working application.  You should get a response status of 200 OK in both cases.  If the certificate was bad you would not get a 200 OK.  You never transmit a certificate only the public key.  So I do not know why you are saying it is missing.

Comment: The authentication is done using TCP protocol which contains validates the TLS encryption.  The TLS is done prior to the request.  It is possible the case that doesn't working is trying to connect to a proxy server to do the authentication while the working case is doing the authentication with a public key (certificated installed on both machines).  So you may have proxy enabled when it should be disabled (so certificate is used).

Comment: The PrivateKey property works slightly different between the two universes, but since SslStream doesn't use the property that's /probably/ a red herring.  (All it means is your private key is being loaded into Windows CNG)

Comment: @bartonjs - Yeah, I'm thinking the debugger simply can't display the private key in Visual Studio 2019 but it can in Visual Studio Code.  That further complicates why the cert is getting dropped on the request unfortunately. :(

Comment: We're facing the same issue. Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @perf-guru - I've been working with MS directly on a fix for about 3 months.  I opened a ticket with their tech support thru my MSDN subscription.  So far, there's been no solution or resolution.  They have had a number of teams involved and we are scheduled to meet again sometime Monday.  I'll post an update here if/when there is a resolution or if it simply could not be resolved.  As our .NET Framework code is soon to be retired, I may have to just call the .NET Core code to get to the API that the Framework can't connect to as a "band-aid" to fix this issue.

Comment: @motor75, thanks! .Net framework and .Net core's implementation is definitely not in sync. In our case, we found the resolution in the way public keys (.cer) were exported. The problem was in the list that server presents of issuers it will accept for client auth. Initially, when the public key was exported using the default cert manager on windows - which although had the base64 encoded information, it was lacking some metadata. When these were shared with our partner and they imported into their apache/spring system, the server would not send the issuer of our client auth cert. 1/2

Comment: Apparently .net core ignores the issuers, but .net framework doesn't - hence it works in .net core - i.e. it attaches the cert to request as seen in wireshark, but .net framework does not do that - it respects the issuers presented by server. While investigating the issue, we accidentally exported/created the .pfx to .cer using openssl. This .cer file has the base64 encoded info along with some metadata. When our partner imported these into their apache/java system, the server started presenting the issuers - which then .net framework played nicely with. It was a hell of a ride. 2/2